# Login redirection does not work

Tags: php, session, cookies, session-cookies

When I login, I have 2 options; Remember Me or Not. Now my problem is with the Remember Me part UNCHECKED. When it is unchecked, this means a session is created.

Now the problem is, when the session is created, if I go directly on the login.php, the session resets, meaning there is no session anymore and I need to login again(which is the index.php)

Here are my codes, I need it to go on post.php when user tries to go to login.php directly after logged in! It works when there is cookies(that is remember me checked) but it doens't when there is a session.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After correct loggin in login.php you have code: `$_SESSION['sess_username'] = $userData['username'];`

but in top of the login.php you check if user is logged by: `isset($_SESSION['username'])`

It should be: `isset($_SESSION['sess_username'])`

Comment: Nice find dude. Fixed it. What a silly mistake from my side. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Now if you say they want to be remembered, you don't put anything in your session variable $_SESSION['sess_username']. So the next page it will be empty wich makes your site think you aren't logged on

---

I never used the function session_write_close();

A quick google delivered me [this](https://www.php.net/session_write_close).

"void session_write_close ( void ) - End the current session and store session data."

Are you sure you are using this correct? As it states it closes the current session.

Comment: -Wesley, doesn't matter if I remove it, when I access login.php directly after I login, it goes back to the login form(index.php) and I need to login again. I don't know how to prevent that. It doesn't work when I check for a session or a cookie and redirect to post.php :S

Comment: I had a similar problem a while back. Let me check and get back to you.

Comment: Mine is working without a problem. I checked your code again and got following things:

  
- shouldn't you use md5 + salt for your pasword protection? (just a tip)  
- in the part of login.php @ "if($rememberMe == TRUE)" you set cookies but you don't create the session.  
- can you check if $_POST['rememberMe'] is actually POSTed?

Comment: Yeah for the password, I'm just using something that simple because my focus right now is to make the login work. After that it's just a matter of hashing and salting. I set cookie but I don't create session because it depends whether remember me is checked or not ;S